# How to draw a triangle with border with Java Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm trying to draw a triangle with a border using the `Graphics.drawPolygon()` method

The triangle is properly drawn, but how can I calculate the 3 points of the border?

I already did it with a circle, but I can't seem to find a solution for triangle.

**A requirement of the instructor as that it cannot use `Graphics2D`.**

My code:

```
if (xPoints != null && yPoints != null) {
    int[] nXPoints = new int[] { xPoints[0] - borderThickness, xPoints[1] - borderThickness,
            xPoints[2] - borderThickness };
    int[] nYPoints = new int[] { yPoints[0] - borderThickness, yPoints[1] - borderThickness,
            yPoints[2] - borderThickness };

    g.setColor(borderColor);
    g.fillPolygon(nXPoints, nYPoints, 3);

    g.setColor(fillColor);
    g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
}
```

**Edit:**
**Expected result**

[image: Expected result]

Comment: I'm confused.  How can you possibly draw the triangle without these points?

Comment: `how can I calculate the 3 points of the border?` - . The draw/fill methods work on the same set of points.

Comment: @JoeC .. I know is not possible to draw it without the points. I'm looking for a way to calculate the points of the border.

Comment: @camickr

No, they don't, check the code again.

Comment: @camickr is correct; the signatures are compatible; but you need to use the correct methods, as shown [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39812618/230513).

Comment: @trashgod

I can't use the same points, because I need the border to have custom thickness

Comment: ***"Better if it doesn't needs the use of Graphics2D."*** ..Why? "How to draw a triangle with border with Java Graphics" Show an image of the intended result.

Comment: My interpretation of this question is that you want to compute some sort of "offset". From the original points, you want to compute 3 new points that describe a triangle that is "larger" than the original one (larger by the `borderThickness`), so that when you paint them one over the other, it *looks like* a triangle with a border. **If** this is right: Don't do this. It would be fiddly to get this right, and even if you get it working, it's a crude hack. Swing (and particularly `Graphics2D`) offers **so** many nice and easy ways to achieve cool effects. Use them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Updated the post with a picture of expected result.

@Marco13 you're right, that's basically what I want. I'm sure it will be a bad hack, but the things is teacher haven't taught me `Graphics2D` so I'm not supposed to use it.

Comment: OK.. so how does the code calculate the x/y positions of the points for the initial triangle? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Leave out the code for the circle that is already working - it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) methods [`drawPolygon()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon-int:A-int:A-int-) to render the outline and [`fillPolygon()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon-int:A-int:A-int-) to fill its interior; both have the required signature, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701097/java-graphics-fillpolygon-how-to-also-render-right-and-bottom-edges/7701684#7701684).

[image: image1]

Because "operations that draw the outline of a figure operate by traversing an infinitely thin path between pixels with a pixel-sized pen," cast the graphics context to [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) so that you can use `draw()` and `fill()` on the corresponding `Shape`. This will allow you to specify the outline using `setStroke()`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823631/java-opaque-color/7824225#7824225).

[image: image2]

> I need it to have a custom thickness…I also don't want to use `Graphics2D`.

Custom thickness is *not* supported in the `Graphics` API. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179415/java2d-is-it-always-safe-to-cast-graphics-into-graphics2d), the actual graphics context received by `paintComponent()` is an instance of `Graphics2D`, which *does* support custom stroke geometry.

> The things is teacher haven't taught me `Graphics2D`, so I'm not supposed to use it.

Then simply paint the larger triangle and then the smaller. If this isn't working, then you have an error in you calculation of the larger triangle, and you should edit your question to include a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

> I'm looking for a way to do it without `Graphics2D`…a guy has interpreted the question properly in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811618/how-to-draw-a-triangle-with-border-with-java-graphics/39812618#comment66918514_39811618).

As @Marco13 [observes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811618/how-to-draw-a-triangle-with-border-with-java-graphics/39812618#comment66918514_39811618), you need a triangle that is larger than the original one by the `borderThickness`. You can use [`AffineTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) to do the scaling. While `Graphics` can't `fill()` an arbitrary [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), such as one created by `AffineTransform`, it can *clip* the rendering as required. In the example below, a unit triangle is translated and scaled to the center of an N x N panel; a copy is enlarged by `delta`. Note how rendering is clipped first to the larger background figure and then to the smaller foreground figure.

[image: GraphicsBorder]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39812618/230513
 */
public class GraphicsBorder {

    private static class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final int N = 256;
        private static final Color FILL = new Color(0x990099);
        private static final Color BORDER = new Color(0x66FFB2);
        private final Shape fore;
        private final Shape back;

        public GraphicsPanel(Polygon polygon, int delta) {
            AffineTransform a1 = new AffineTransform();
            a1.translate(N / 2, N / 2);
            a1.scale(N / 3, N / 3);
            fore = a1.createTransformedShape(polygon);
            AffineTransform a2 = new AffineTransform();
            a2.translate(N / 2, N / 2 - delta / 3);
            a2.scale(N / 3 + delta, N / 3 + delta);
            back = a2.createTransformedShape(polygon);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(BORDER);
            g.setClip(back);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, N, N);
            g.setColor(FILL);
            g.setClip(fore);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, N, N);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(N, N);
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GraphicsBorder");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(0, -1);
        p.addPoint(1, 1);
        p.addPoint(-1, 1);
        f.add(new GraphicsPanel(p, 16));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GraphicsBorder()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can use the same points for the border, because I need it to have a custom thickness

Comment: These two requirements conflict; I've elaborated above.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm looking for a way to do it without `Graphics2D`... I know `Graphics` doesn't support stroke, but there should be a way to do it. 

A guy has interpreted the question properly in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811618/how-to-draw-a-triangle-with-border-with-java-graphics#comment66918514_39811618)

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva: I've added an example above.