# DrawLine in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Main idea is - when values the of the slider are growing, more lines are dividing equal parts of the component and don’t cross the lines of polygon (like it’s in upper left corner of the picture). I want to do this with all the corners but now I only did it with one of them.

Can someone tell me what I need to change to get my lines to 1/3 of Width?

My values are good for 1/2 but not for 1/3, `n` is a variable for slider.

[image]

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Mariusz extends JFrame {

    private int n = 5;
    private Color kolor = Color.RED;

    MyComponent komponent = null;

    private class MyComponent extends JComponent
    {
        protected void paintComponent (Graphics grafika)
        {
            grafika.setColor(kolor);
            grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * 1/3, 0, 0, getHeight() * 1/3);
            grafika.drawLine(0, getHeight() * 1/3, getWidth() * 1/3, getHeight());
            grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * 1/3, getHeight(),getWidth(), getHeight() * 1/3);
            grafika.drawLine(getWidth(), getHeight() * 1/3, getWidth() * 1/3, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
            {
                if (i <= n / 3)
                {
                    grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * i /n, 0, getWidth() * i /n, (getHeight() - getHeight() * 2/3 ) -  getHeight() * i / n); //lewy gorny
                    grafika.drawLine(  getWidth() * i / n,(getHeight() - getHeight() * 2/3 ) +  getHeight() * i / n + getHeight() *1/3, getWidth() * i / n, getHeight() );
                }
                if (i > n / 3)
                {
                    grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * i / n   , 0, getWidth() * i /n,   getHeight() * 2 * i /n / 3   - getHeight() * 1 /3  );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Mariusz(String string) 
    {
        super(string);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = kit.getScreenSize();
        setBounds( d.width / 4, d.height / 4, d.width / 2, d.height / 2);

        add (komponent = new MyComponent());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        final JSlider slider = new  JSlider(3,40,n);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                n = slider.getValue();
                komponent.repaint();

            }
        });
        panel.add(slider);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new  Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Mariusz("triangles");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: Explain better what works and what doesn't and how you want it to work. 2 sentences aren't enough.

Comment: Are you looking for `setStroke()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39812618/230513)?

Comment: @user1803551 Okay :) Main idea is - when values of slider are growing, lines are dividing for equal parts and don’t cross the lines of polygon ( like it’s in upper left corner). I want to do this with all the corners but now I only did it with one of them.

Comment: @trashgod Now im trying to do this with `drawLine()` but with `Graphics2D` it can be easier so I will try it if I don't succed.

Comment: @Kuba_or_JJ: All supported platforms provide a concrete implementation of `Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is ad-hoc and I cant follow that it will suceed in other measures (4/5 etc).

Heres an approach thats based on similar triangles:

starting from the upper right and working backwards:

```
h1/h2=(2*w/3)/(2*w/3-(1/n)*(2*w/3))
```

thus

```
h2=h1/(.....)
```

where h1=h/3.

Converting this to code

```
    double f=2./3, f2=1-f;

    g2.setColor(Color.blue);

    for (int i=n-1; i>-1; i--)
    {
      grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * (n-i) / n, 0, getWidth() * (n-i)/n,  
        (int)((getHeight()/ 3)/(f/(f-1.*i/n))) );
    }
```

For the upper left we work the same way but with factor f2:

```
g2.setColor(Color.green);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * i / n   , 0, getWidth() * i /n,   (int)((getHeight()/ 3)/(f2/(f2-1.*i/n))) );
    }
```

The same for the lower left:

```
g2.setColor(Color.magenta);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * i / n   , getHeight()-(int)((2*getHeight()/ 3)/(f2/(f2-1.*i/n))), getWidth() * i /n,   getHeight() );
    }
```

and lower right

```
g2.setColor(Color.black);

    for (int i=n-1; i>-1; i--)
    {
      grafika.drawLine(getWidth() * (n-i) / n   , getHeight()-(int)((2*getHeight()/ 3)/(f/(f-1.*i/n))), getWidth() * (n-i) /n,  getHeight()  );
    }
```

If you want a 4/5 measure for example you would have to change f=4./5 and all the 2*getHeight()/3 to 4*getHeight()/5(getHeight()/3 to getHeight()/5 etc).

Comment: The expression `(2*w/3)/(2*w/3-(1/n)*(2*w/3))` is just `1/(1-n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a different approach. Instead of struggling with the math of drawing the lines from the edges until the meet the polygon, draw regular, full, vertical lines, and then overlay the polygon over them.

First, 3 things to set up:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {

    super.paintComponent(graphics);

    Graphics2D grafika = (Graphics2D) graphics;
```

1. Always call the `super` method as the first thing you do in a `paintComponent` to avoid artifacts (unless you know what you're doing).
2. It's always safe to cast the `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2D`, more advanced, object.
3. Saved the width and height to local variables to decrease the number of calls inside `paintComponent()`.

Now, draw the lines using this very simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    grafika.drawLine(w * i / n, 0, w * i / n, h);
```

which is just a reduction of your loop. You might need to modify it according to your requirements, but note that the `y` coordinates stretch the full component height.

[image]

Then create a `Polygon` from the points you have in the `drawLine` methods:

```
Polygon poly = new Polygon();
poly.addPoint(w * 1 / 3, 0);
poly.addPoint(0, h * 1 / 3);
poly.addPoint(w * 1 / 3, h);
poly.addPoint(w, h * 1 / 3);
```

Finally, set a color for filling this shape, draw it, set the color for outlining the shape and draw it again:

```
grafika.setColor(getBackground());
grafika.fill(poly); // draws the inside
grafika.setColor(kolor);
grafika.draw(poly); // draws the outline
```

[image]

Hopefully, this is not considered cheating..

Also, this line

```
add(komponent = new MyComponent());
```

looks like a source for trouble *in my opinion*. Do split it into 2.

Comment: Thanks for showing that way of solution, it's also useful for me.

Comment: @Kuba_or_JJ You can upvote the answer if it was useful.

Comment: I did it but I have less  than 15 reputation  and my vote is not visible.

Comment: @Kuba_or_JJ Oh right, you can't vote yet. No worries, when you get to 15 points and if you remember come back and upvote it :)